# Stackoverflow Mobile User Profile count as days consecutive

Tags: support, mobile-web, consecutive-days

If I log in via the mobile app does this count towards my count? As at weekends I mostly don't boot up my laptop unless it is for a specific purpose.

I was happy with the mobile app as it allowed me to write quick responses and catch up on some answers quickly if needed.

The reason I was asking was I has a 20 day consecutive count up until sunday morning but didn't log in via the browser just the mobile app, and now my count has been reset back to 1.

Can someone explain to me why this has happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the mobile site records visits. I use the mobile site extensively, and I haven't lost a day due to that ^.^

A "visit" does not just amount to opening the site--you need to *do something*. Comment, vote, post, *something*. I think there's a certain level of activity (just a single vote *may* not work--you may need two or three) that you need to get to.

Just be active, look at a few posts, post comments and vote here and there, the day will be recorded. :)

Comment: Generally i dont leave a comment unless i know a bit about the area, mostly i just read the questions and answers to help get a thought on the areas i work in. shouldnt this count as activity?

Comment: @Qpirate: Nope. Participation counts as activity.

Comment: @Qpirate: An easy way to check if a visit has been recorded is to see the **Last Seen** section under your profile.